# Can't use tools like window tidy on osx mavericks

Tags: osx-mavericks, accessibility

I've installed Mac OSX Mavericks. I have Window Tidy installed, but the tool says, that it is blocked by the operating systems.
[image]
How can I continue using the tool on mavericks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can re-enable it by changing some settings which were set during the installation of maverick.

1. Open the `System-Preferences`
2. Open the `Security & Privacy`-Menu
3. Now switch to the `Privacy`-tab
   [image]
4. Now you have to unlock the tab. You will now be able to check the accessibility-tools and allow them to control your computer.

[Source](http://sots.name/blog/2013/10/16/window-tidy-and-cheatsheet-in-mavericks-os-x-10-dot-9/)